# Unit testing DOM elements outside directive

Tags: jasmine, karma-runner

How to test DOM elements outside directive like add and remove 'active' class to the tabs based on input. Help me to write unit test case for angular.element('.active').removeClass('active');

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
<div id="tabs">
<div id="tab1" class="active" tab-navigation>Tab 1</div>
<div id="tab2" tab-navigation>Tab 2</div>
<div id="tab3" tab-navigation>Tab 3</div>
</div>
<div class="active" id="tab">  
<input type="text" ng-model=inputvalue" my-directive/>
<button value="submit"/>
</div>
</div>

app.directive('myDirective',function(){
return{
require:'ngModel',
link:function(scope,element,attr,ngModelCtrl){
ngModelCtrl.$parsers.unshift(function(inputValue)
{
 if(inputValue==='') {
 angular.element('.active').removeClass('active');
}    
};
});
```